# Parsing XML schema java

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, jaxb, xsom

I need to parse XML schema (source can be wsdl file or xsd ) and extract all the complex types and their constituent elements with their types.. I have used JAXB (xjc)but it does not return me a list of all complexTypes . Which alternative (XSOM) should I use? I would prefer some built-in library in jdk6.

`

```
 <element name="BankLoanProcessRequest">   
   <complexType>
     <sequence>
    <element name="ClientId" type="int"/>
    <element name="LoanAmount" type="double"/>
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
 </element>`
```

Comment: I thought XSOM is allowing extraction of complex types. Are you sure you can't make it with XSOM?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.. I have tried it with XSOM..and its working for xsd files but not for schema defined inside WSDL. It throws exception on transforming wsdl file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JDOM or DOM4j-

here are the link -

http://www.jdom.org/

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/